# Java Reading .txt file to 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, multidimensional-array

So i have an assignment that is requiring me to use 10 threads to read 10 columns of data from a matrix .txt file.  Im having trouble converting the file into a 2d array as im always getting a NumberFormatException.  The style of the file looks like this for 10 columns and 1000 rows of 10k elements.  in the txt file itself the numbers are formatted in columns with different white space between each record.

```
9510.0      5880.0      8923.0      21849.0     3295.0      17662.0     23931.0     31401.0     13211.0     18942.0     
11034.0     9002.0      4162.0      4821.0      4217.0      7849.0      22837.0     19178.0     24492.0     14838.0     
7895.0      7337.0      18115.0     8949.0      28492.0     22067.0     12714.0     21234.0     26497.0     18003.0     
846.0       29493.0     21868.0     26037.0     27137.0     28630.0     20373.0     8274.0      21280.0     11475.0     
26069.0     21295.0     16883.0     4448.0      20317.0     21063.0     3540.0      23934.0     14843.0     2757.0      
19348.0     32207.0     7833.0      5495.0      26138.0     20905.0     16135.0     19840.0     10829.0     5993.0      
12538.0     16205.0     18997.0     29450.0     6740.0      970.0       7004.0      17142.0     677.0       23509.0     
5243.0      14107.0     24050.0     8179.0      20050.0     24130.0     13494.0     22593.0     3032.0      7580.0
```

Here is the code i have been testing along with Scanner implementations as well.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MainThread {

    public static int rows, cols;
    public static int[][] cells;
    /**
     * main reads the file and starts
     * the graphical display
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         // Read the entire file in
        List<String> myFileLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("bigMatrix.txt"));

        // Remove any blank lines
        for (int i = myFileLines.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (myFileLines.get(i).isEmpty()) {
                myFileLines.remove(i);
            }
        }

        // Declare you 2d array with the amount of lines that were read from the file
        double[][] intArray = new double[myFileLines.size()][];

        // Iterate through each row to determine the number of columns
        for (int i = 0; i < myFileLines.size(); i++) {
            // Split the line by spaces
            String[] splitLine = myFileLines.get(i).split("\\s");

            // Declare the number of columns in the row from the split
            intArray[i] = new double[splitLine.length]; 
            for (int j = 0; j < splitLine.length; j++) {
                // Convert each String element to an integer
                intArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[j]);
            }
        }

        // Print the integer array
        for (double[] row : intArray) {
            for (double col : row) {
                System.out.printf("%5d ", col);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    }
```

Any help would be great, I also know some about threads and implementing the Runnable interface, but any ideas on how to calculate the maximum value of each column along with average thatd be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

As the name of the exception suggests, `9510.0` for example is not of the correct Integer format due to `.0` part implying a float or a double. Use `Float.parseFloat()` and an array of `float` or if you really want, a cast to int with `intArray[i][j] = (int) Float.parseFloat(splitLine[j]);`

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two problems with your code that can lead to a NumberFormatException.

The first is that you are doing `split("\\s")` which will split on a single whitespace character. This means that two spaces next to each other will cause an empty string to be "between" them and this empty string isn't parseable into a number.

The second is that you're using `Integer.parseInt()` on numbers that are non-integers (they have a fractional portion). You probably want `Double.parseDouble()` here.

Finally, there is nothing in your sample code discussing what you're trying to do with threads or why. If you have a question about threads, please open them up as another question since they appear unrelated to this one.